# Encryption and Decryption by different providers

Tags: java, security, encryption

Suppose I use AES Encryption using provider A, Can I Decrypt the same using provider B?

Comment: Yes unless one or both of them are buggy.

Comment: Yes, assuming you use the same key, IV and block chaining mode.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to answer someone quickly.  Did not have much time to try it out by myself.  Thanks again.

Comment: Why are people voting to close as "not constructive"? It seems a clear-cut question to me.

Comment: I commented honestly.  But now I am blocked from asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you should specify not only the algorithm (`AES`), but also mode and padding (e.g. `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`).

The [JCA Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Cipher) says that:

> (Creating a Cipher Object) If no mode or padding is specified, provider-specific default values for the mode and padding scheme are used. For example, the SunJCE provider uses ECB as the default mode, and PKCS5Padding as the default padding scheme for DES, DES-EDE and Blowfish ciphers. This means that in the case of the SunJCE provider:
>   `Cipher.getInstance("DES")` and `Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")` are equivalent statements.

If you only specify `AES`, it could be the case that the other provider implements a different default, and that will not work (e.g. you will encrypt with CBC and decrypt with ECB).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's standardized algorithm, Things like padding and mode of operations need to be the set the same on both providers for you to be able to decrypt though.

Answer (score 0):

Probably. There were a number of algorithms being thrown around for AES in its early days. I recall one program that supported the two fish variant. The one that became the standard is Rijndael. These days unless otherwise specified you can assume that AES is actually AES-Rijndael. If it specified any other AES algorithm, like Two Fish, you will be in trouble.